# Python: Django: How to run django app using a python script

Tags: python, django

I've a python file named "config.py" which actually checks the ip of user and run the django server on that port accordingly. 
 The method I used there was to create a batch file using python and execute it later.

```
import socket
import subprocess
x = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
x = str(x)
with open("run.bat", "w") as f:
    f.write(f'manage.py runserver {x}:0027')
subprocess.call([r'run.bat'])
```

But this method is not very effective. I want a way like:
`import something`
`something.run("manage.py")`

or something accordingly

 Kindly Help me doing this
Edit:
I've seen Django's manage.py.
Can I edit this file (the sys.argv section) in such a way that it automatically runs a server on 192.168.x.x:8000 just by clicking on manage.py?

Please help

Comment: not sure what you actually want to do, but if you want to check the IP, then use `middleware` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the method you're trying to reach is to run a shell command inside a python script, which can be achieved by using the [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) function.

You can use it in your code as the following:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import os
x = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
x = str(x)
os.system(f'manage.py runserver {x}:0027')
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much

Comment: @Ojas_Gupta Great! Don't forget to accept as the answer ;D

Comment: Hi! @Bernardo Duarte
, would you like to please edit your answer according to edited question please?
Thank you very much

Comment: @Ojas_Gupta I believe it is a whole new question, I think you should create a new one due to community guidelines and for better visibility so that I or someone else can help you ;D

Comment: You can also do `subprocess.call(['manage.py', 'runserver', x + ':0027'])` instead of the `os.system` line.